# Asp.net applications suddenly don't keep sessions anymore while running in localhost

Tags: asp.net, session, localhost, iis-express, asp.net-session

Every aspnet web application I try to run locally just doesn't keep sessions anymore.
Somehow, this happens on both VS 2013 & 2015 with different projects. I haven't touched anything, one morning I found out that after a redirect every session data is lost.
These applications are still working on production and dev environments.

Answer (score 0):

> A proxy server or firewall on the web server side is stripping out the
>   cookie. It may be that the user is correctly storing and sending the
>   session cookie, but that the hardware on the web server's side is
>   stripping out the cookie before it can be read by the ASP or ASP.NET
>   engine, causing the server to generate a new SessionID and a new
>   cookie for the user on each request.

Comment: Please upvote or mark as answer if it adds something useful. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but nothing has changed on the web.            As I said, this is a local-only issue that happened out of the blue

Comment: 1) Start–> Administrative Tools –> Services

2) right click over the ASP.NET State Service and click “start”

*additionally you could set the service to automatic so that it will work after a reboot.

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error related to session?

Comment: Also go through this link-
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2006/08/02/asp-net-case-study-lost-session-variables-and-appdomain-recycles/

Comment: Nope, no errors. I just lose every single session, as if I never declared them.
And as I said, this problem is localhost/local/machine-only, the published versions are working.